# How to draw a hole on shape with matplolib

Tags: python, matplotlib, gradient, imshow

I draw a filled circle with imshow and plt.circle :

```
sun_back = ax.imshow(np.linspace(0, 1, 100).reshape(-1, 1), cmap='plasma', vmin=0, vmax=100, 
                     extent=[..., ..., ..., ...])

sun_back.set_clip_path(plt.Circle((0, 10), 20, transform=ax.transData))
```

And then i know how to plot a line on it, but i don't want filled line, i want a hole on this circle but i don't know how to "drill" two zorder with a shape.

[image: circle with line]

unlike the picture, I want the black bars to be the same color as the background, but this one is dynamic so i can't change the color with the code. It need to be transparent.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `matplotlib`, you can only create the ***union*** of several paths but here you need the ***difference*** between the cirle and the rectangles. So unless you want to do the maths yourself I recommend using `shapely` to get this difference between the clip objects. [`difference`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#object.difference) gives you a multipolygon:

```
cp_shape = circle.difference(rect1).difference(rect2).difference(rect3)
```

[image]

You can then convert the exterior of all polygons of that multipolygon into paths and use [`make_compound_path`](https://matplotlib.org/api/path_api.html#matplotlib.path.Path.make_compound_path) to combine them into one clip path:

```
clip_path = mp.Path.make_compound_path(*[mp.Path(np.array(p.exterior.xy).T) for p in cp_shape])
```

Example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.path as mp
import numpy as np
import shapely.geometry as sg

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.NullLocator())
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(plt.NullLocator())
ax.patch.set_color('r')
sun_back = ax.imshow(np.broadcast_to(np.linspace(100, 0, 100), (100, 100)).T, 
                     cmap='plasma',
                     extent=[0,200,0,200]
                     )

circle = sg.Point(100,100).buffer(70)
rect1 = sg.box(30,50,170,58)
rect2 = sg.box(30,65,170,70)
rect3 = sg.box(30,75,170,78)
cp_shape = circle.difference(rect1).difference(rect2).difference(rect3)
clip_path = mp.Path.make_compound_path(*[mp.Path(np.array(p.exterior.xy).T) for p in cp_shape])

sun_back.set_clip_path(clip_path, transform=ax.transData)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks ! after few hours, I succeeded thanks to your example !